# c++ error: object of abstract class type "..." is not allowed

Tags: c++

I want to use polymorphism in my program but don't know why when I create

```
virtual void setVertices()=0;
```

in class CFigure i get an error

```
C2259: 'CRectangle': cannot instantiate abstract class (line 63 and 74)
IntelliSense: object of abstract class type "CRectangle" is not allowed:
pure virtual function "CFigure:setVertices" has no overrider (line 63 and 74)
```

I want also to declare:

```
virtual void setVertices(CFigure& fig) = 0;
```

I don't know at all that if I can write CFigure& fig cuz CRectangle i have:

```
 void setVertices(CRectangle& fig)
```

and those two methods have different parameters.
Can someone can tell me how to help me to explain those errors and tell me how to fix my program? Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

class Point2D{
    int x, y;
public:
    void setX(int X){ x = X; }
    void setY(int Y){ y = Y; }

    int getX(){ return x; }
    int getY(){ return y; }

};


class CFigure :public Point2D
{
protected:
    Point2D Vert[4];

public:
    CFigure(){}

    //virtual void setVertices(CFigure& fig) = 0;
    virtual void setVertices()=0;// if I comment this line all works good
};

class CRectangle : public CFigure
{

public:
    CRectangle(){}

    void setVertices(CRectangle& fig)
    {
        //CRectangle fig;
        int x1, y1, a;
        cout << "Give x1, y1" << endl;
        cin >> x1 >> y1;
        cout << "Give a" << endl;
        cin >> a;

        fig.Vert[0].setX(x1);
        fig.Vert[0].setY(y1);

        fig.Vert[1].setX(x1 + a);
        fig.Vert[1].setY(y1);

        fig.Vert[2].setX(x1);
        fig.Vert[2].setY(y1 + a);

        fig.Vert[3].setX(x1 + a);
        fig.Vert[3].setY(y1 + a);

    }


    void showPoints()
    {
        CRectangle f;
        setVertices(f);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            cout << "P" << i << "( " << f.Vert[i].getX() << " " << f.Vert[i].getY() << " ) " << endl;
        }
    }

};
int main()
{
    CRectangle ag;
    ag.showPoints();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ does not have contravariance for virtual functions.

Comment: Yes, the overriding version must match the pure virtual version in what parameters it takes. When you declare the pure virtual function in the base class, you need to specify what parameters it should have.

Comment: The design is pretty flawed. You usually don't use `std::cin` for functions like `setVertices()` but pass a `std::istream&` parameter instead.

Comment: `void setVertices(CRectangle& fig)`  doesn't make sense for a member function.  Make changes to `this` instead and make the function `void setVertices()`.

Comment: I don't quite follow your logic. First, you create a rectangle, `ag`. Then you ask `ag` to "show points", which creates *another*  rectangle that it outputs and throws away. I would expect `ag.showPoints()` to display the coordinates of `ag`.

Comment: thx molbdinlo cuz of u I understand my mistake. I'm just learning

Comment: Also, I'm confused why a `CFigure` _is_ a point, and also _contains_ four points.  That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFigure` declares `setVertices()` as:

```
virtual void setVertices()=0;
```

But `CRectangle` declares `setVertices()` as:

```
void setVertices(CRectangle& fig)
```

The additional parameter makes it so `CRectangle::setVertices()` is not *overriding* `CFigure::setVertices()`. It is *overloading* it instead.  That is why the compiler is complaining that `CRectangle` is an abstract class - it really is.  When you *override* a virtual method, the signature of the overriding method must *exactly* match the signature of the method that is being overridden, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Point2D
{
    int x, y;
public:
    void setX(int X){ x = X; }
    void setY(int Y){ y = Y; }

    int getX(){ return x; }
    int getY(){ return y; }    
};

class CFigure : public Point2D
{
protected:
    Point2D Vert[4];

public:
    CFigure() {}

    virtual void setVertices()=0;
};

class CRectangle : public CFigure
{
public:
    CRectangle() {}

    void setVertices()
    {
        int x1, y1, a;
        cout << "Give x1, y1" << endl;
        cin >> x1 >> y1;
        cout << "Give a" << endl;
        cin >> a;

        Vert[0].setX(x1);
        Vert[0].setY(y1);

        Vert[1].setX(x1 + a);
        Vert[1].setY(y1);

        Vert[2].setX(x1);
        Vert[2].setY(y1 + a);

        Vert[3].setX(x1 + a);
        Vert[3].setY(y1 + a);
    }

    void showPoints()
    {
        setVertices();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            cout << "P" << i << "( " << Vert[i].getX() << " " << Vert[i].getY() << " ) " << endl;
        }
    }    
};

int main()
{
    CRectangle ag;
    ag.showPoints();
    return 0;
}
```